# Pushing fragment onclick of a button or icon on actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

### What i am trying to do:

- I am trying to achieve a representation as below
- As seen in the image on click of `button`slide the `fragment-2`from the left
- Here `fragment-2` is not on top of `fragment-1` but instead `fragment-1` is being pushed  making 15% of `fragment-1` visible
- Even the action bar is being pushed to right

Note: I am not speaking about drawer implementation where a layer is on top of another

Are there any Github implementations for this any samples etc, thanks

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this repository:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

They also provide a sample app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example

Comment: @ Ismael Di Vita .......... But i have one more question ..... How to achieve this without using actionbar sherlock library ... is it possible ?